# Simple way to nest json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Should be very easy but I have been stuck on this. 
Getting data from Mysql with Json output that is missing a default nesting

```
$row->execute();
$item=array();
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{   
    $testnab['Src']=$rec['src'];


array_push($item,$testnab);     


}

echo json_encode($item,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Result:

```
[ { "Src": "test1st" }, { "Src": "test3rd" } ]
```

I need the output to be:

```
[{"0": { "Src": "test1st" }},{"0": { "Src": "test3rd" }}]
```

it is non-sequential with "0" being constant

Comment: $testnab = array(0=>array('Src'=>$rec['src']))

Comment: @HeruPrasetyoUtomo Please never post solutions as comments (that's not where they belong, they don't enjoy the same formatting features as answers, they cannot be downvoted when they are incorrect/inadvisable, they can lead to question abandonment, they role model bad behavior to other users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense all of your declaration logic into one line and avoid the push call.

Nest your resultset row value inside a cast object.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NvDbs))

```
$resultset = [
    ['src' => 'test1st'],
    ['src' => 'test3rd'],
];

foreach ($resultset as $row) {   
    $item[] = (object)[['Src' => $row['src']]];
}

echo json_encode($item);
```

Output:

```
[{"0":{"Src":"test1st"}},{"0":{"Src":"test3rd"}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an object with $testnab as a property value:

```
$item=array();
foreach($row as $rec)//foreach loop  
{   
    $testnab['Src']=$rec['src'];
    $o = new StdClass;
    $o->{'0'} = $testnab;
    array_push($item,$o);     
}
echo json_encode($item);
```

Output:

```
[{"0":{"Src":"test1st"}},{"0":{"Src":"test3rd"}}]
```